# How to use navigation stack for line following with opencv

Tags: navigation, kinect, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying understand what exactly is the use of navigation stack and how I can leverage navigation stack for Line following robot(AGV), I just want simple object avoidance with laser data and to follow a line with opencv camera.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296324/how-to-use-navigation-stack-for-line-following-with-opencv/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there Prof. Xavier, you definitely want to check out:
[Programming Robots with ROS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do), especially chapter 12: Follow-bot, that is exactly what you are looking for. A robot that follows a yellow line using a camera only, using gazebo for the simulation.

You can even check out their code at: https://github.com/osrf/rosbook/tree/master/followbot

Some pictures from the project:
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

And the book is a piece of beauty, written by OSRF themselves, check it out! Most of the code is on python, so it's easy to get used to.
Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-08-05**:
thank you, your help helped me a lot, keep helping <3